# What is Causing my Code to Not Return Any Data When Trying to Send a Login Request to a Local Server?

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite, unity-game-engine

For about a month, I have been trying to figure out why my code will not return anything after posting a wwwForm (I have also tried the newer equivalent of this function but I had no luck with that either.) The nameField and passwordField are taken from text boxes within the game and the code used in my login script is copied and pasted from a Register script but I have changed the file location to the login.php file. The register script works fine and I can add new users to my database but the login script only outputs "Form Sent." and not the "present" that should return when the form is returned and it never gets any further than that point meaning that it lets the user through with no consequence if they use an invalid name because the script never returns an answer. What should I do to fix this?

Thanks,

Unity Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField nameField;
    public InputField passwordField;

    public Button acceptSubmissionButton;

    public void CallLogInCoroutine()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LogIn());
    }

    IEnumerator LogIn()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("username", nameField.text);
        form.AddField("password", passwordField.text);
        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost/sqlconnect/login.php", form);
        Debug.Log("Form Sent.");
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log("Present");
        if (www.text[0] == '0')
        {
            Debug.Log("Present2");
            DatabaseManager.username = nameField.text;
            DatabaseManager.score = int.Parse(www.text.Split('\t')[1]);
            Debug.Log("Log In Success.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User Login Failed. Error #" + www.text);
        }

    }

    public void Validation()
    {
        acceptSubmissionButton.interactable = nameField.text.Length >= 7 && passwordField.text.Length >= 8;
    }
}
```

login.php:

```
<?php
echo "Test String2";
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'computer science coursework');

// check for successful connection.
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "1: Connection failed"; // Error code #1 - connection failed.
        exit();
    }

$username = mysqli_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
$usernameClean = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$password = $_POST["password"];

if($username != $usernameClean)
{
    echo "7: Illegal Username, Potential SQL Injection Query. Access Denied.";
    exit();
}

// check for if the name already exists.

$namecheckquery = "SELECT username, salt, hash, score FROM players WHERE username='" . $usernameClean . "';";

$namecheck = mysqli_query($con, $namecheckquery) or die("2: Name check query failed"); // Error code # 2 - name check query failed.

if (mysqli_num_rows($namecheck) != 1)
{
    echo "5: No User With Your Log In Details Were Found Or More Than One User With Your Log In Details Were Found"; // Error code #5 - other than 1 user found with login details
    exit();
}

// get login info from query
$existinginfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($namecheck);
$salt = $existinginfo["salt"];
$hash = $existinginfo["hash"];

$loginhash = crypt($password, $salt);
if ($hash != $loginhash)
{
    echo "6: Incorrect Password"; // error code #6 - password does not hash to match table
    exit;
}
echo "Test String2";
echo"0\t" . $existinginfo["score"];

?>
```

Comment: Have you, by any chance, checked the server's error logs?

Comment: When going through the logs, the only changes made to the logs when I click the login button are these: 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020:19:36:18 +0000] "GET /sqlconnect/echoTest.php HTTP/1.1" 200 17
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2020:19:36:27 +0000] "POST /sqlconnect/login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 27. I don't think this is showing any errors and the echo test works fine.

Comment: which version of unity are you using?? WWW has been depreciated

Comment: @BugFinder 2019.1.11f1 However I tried using the replacement for WWW and that was unsuccessful as well. The Register script also uses WWW and seems to work with no issues.

Comment: What exactly do you get? Is it saying its failing yet you see code 200 showing success in the logs? If so, perhaps its because you echo test string2 first, so text[0] is not 0 but T

Comment: I get nothing back from this code when it runs. When debug.Log the code, it prints to the console all the way up until yield return www and then it does not return. So it never reaches the if statement to cause an error. I think that I added the echo test string2 at a later date to try and find out whether the program was even able to print anything from the .php file (which it was not able to do.) But to summarise, when I run the code, it completes up to the yield return point and then it never moves past that point, but it does not stop. As it's a coroutine, the program loads the next scene.

Comment: What do you mean by `loads the next scene`? In the code you show us there is nothing for loading a scene .. this seems to happen in another script ... Coroutines are not further executed if the according object gets disabled or destroyed (which is usually the case when loading another scene) ... =>  You have to wait for the results before switching scenes ofcourse!

Comment: Sorry, the scene is changed when the player presses "Play Game" on the next menu. I have tried waiting on the next menu for a period of time but it has never returned a user. The coroutine will be destroyed when the player starts the game as you say. I hope the problem isn't as simple as just waiting much longer for the coroutine to complete! I will try tonight.

Comment: Then you should disable this button and only enable it once you got your results back.

Comment: I just tried leaving the coroutine to run after pressing the login button so that it wouldn't be destroyed. The test ran for over an hour but the results never came back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by changing the IENumerator LogIn() to IENumerator Start(). The program ran correctly when it was started at the beginning of a scene but not when it was triggered by a button being pressed. Weirdly, the Register() function in another script (which shares a lot of its code with this one) ran fine when triggered from a button. I'm not sure why this is.

```html
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField nameField;
    public InputField passwordField;

    public Button acceptSubmissionButton;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("username", nameField.text);
        form.AddField("password", passwordField.text);
        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost/sqlconnect/login.php", form);
        Debug.Log("Form Sent.");
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log("Present");
        if (www.text[0] == '0')
        {
            Debug.Log("Present2");
            DatabaseManager.username = nameField.text;
            DatabaseManager.score = int.Parse(www.text.Split('\t')[1]);
            Debug.Log("Log In Success.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("User Login Failed. Error #" + www.text);
        }

    }

    public void Validation()
    {
        acceptSubmissionButton.interactable = nameField.text.Length >= 7 && passwordField.text.Length >= 8;
    }
}
```